# Creating DOMDocument: match one certain element in a PHP-parser

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, domdocument

good evening dear Community,

Well first of all: felize Navidad - I wanna wish you a Merry Christmas!! In my season-break i am workin on a little parser-script.

Today i'm trying to debug a little DOMDocument object in php. Ideally it'd be nice if 
I could get DOMDocument to output in a array-like format, to store the data 
in a database!

My example: [head over to the url - see the example: the target](http://schulen.bildung-rp.de/gehezu/startseite/einzelanzeige.html?tx_wfqbe_pi1%5buid%5d=60119)

I want to filter out the data in the block:

```
Schulart: BBS
Schulnummer:60119
Anschrift: Berufsbildende Schule Boppard Antoniusstr. 21; 56154 Boppard
Telefon: (0 67 42) 80 61-0
Telefax: (0 67 42) 80 61-29
E-Mail: sekretary@bbs-boppard.de
Internet: website 
Träger:Kreisverwaltung Rhein-Hunsr&#65533;ck-Kreis
letzte Änderung: 08 Feb 2010 14:33:12 von 60119
```

I have investigated the sourcecode - and found out that the attribute of interest should 
be this one:
 `class="content"div class="content"><!-- TYPO3SEARCH_begin -->`
or even better: `wfqbeResults`

So if i run the DOMDucument way i can use this like so:

```
$dom->getElementById('wfqbeResults');
```

here the code is: - my trails

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile(' -> here the website goes in<- ');
$divElement = $dom->getElementById('wfqbeResults');

$innerHTML= '';
$children = $divElement->childNodes;
foreach ($children as $child) {
   $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );
} 
echo $innerHTML;

<?
```

Duhh: this outputs lot of garbage. The code spits out a lot of html anyway. I have to 
overhaul the code a bit to get the wanted 9 lines out of the parser:

**what is aimed:** i want to get out the following:

**a.** 9 lines with nine labels and nine values.
**b.** I want to prepare the output to store it in a MySQL-DB!

Look forward to some hints 
greetings zero

Comment: hiello ajreal - thx for answering - i will do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution return the labels and values in a formatted array ready for input to mysql!

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://schulen.bildung-rp.de/gehezu/startseite/einzelanzeige.html?tx_wfqbe_pi1%5buid%5d=60119');
$divElement = $dom->getElementById('wfqbeResults');

$innerHTML= '';
$children = $divElement->childNodes;
foreach ($children as $child) {
$innerHTML = $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($innerHTML);
//$divElementNew = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
$divElementNew = $dom->getElementsByTagname('td');

    /*** the array to return ***/
    $out = array();
    foreach ($divElementNew as $item)
    {
        /*** add node value to the out array ***/
        $out[] = $item->nodeValue;
    }

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
echo '</pre>';

} 

?>
```

Comment: Hello Cocacola09, good day. Many many thanks for your Answer. All looks very very good. This is more than expected. It is a great asset of learning! I get a great starting point for my programming-work here. Thx - you are great! many greetings, zero